# OSX 10.10.3 crashes WebView on dealloc

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, webview

After updating to 10.10.3 the WebView component started to crash after `dealloc`

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [self.webView.windowScriptObject setValue:nil forKey:@"CocoaApp"];
    [[self.webView mainFrame] stopLoading];
    [self.webView setUIDelegate:nil];
    [self.webView setEditingDelegate:nil];
    [self.webView setFrameLoadDelegate:nil];
    [self.webView setPolicyDelegate:nil];
    [self.webView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

The crash happens somewhere deep in WebView

**EXC_BAD_ACCESS**

```
1   0x7fff910bae9e WebDocumentLoaderMac::detachFromFrame()
2   0x7fff920288c0 WebCore::FrameLoader::detachFromParent()
3   0x7fff910d0e55 -[WebView(WebPrivate) _close]
4   0x7fff910d0c49 -[WebView dealloc]
5   0x7fff8b1cf89c objc_object::sidetable_release(bool)
6   0x7fff8b1b5e8f (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*)
7   0x7fff912b26f2 _CFAutoreleasePoolPop
8   0x7fff8830e762 -[NSAutoreleasePool drain]
9   0x7fff8e3f0cc1 -[NSApplication run]
10  0x7fff8e36d354 NSApplicationMain
11  0x1000ebb12 main
12  0x7fff8c81e5c9 start
13  0x3
```

**Any ideas? Is this a Apple bug? It started AFTER 10.10.3?**

It doesn't crash when NSZombie is enabled!

Comment: Normally if you enable NSZombie, it should tell you which object receive a message after being deallocated. Could you check which object is that?

Comment: Nope, because the crash, or any other problem doesn't happen when NSZombie is enabled :( and it happens deep inside the webview component

Comment: Are you setting any other delegates and not nilling them out? https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Classes/WebView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001903-SW21

I had this problem a couple weeks ago and it turns out I was forgetting to nil out one of the delegates

Comment: nope, all delegates are nilled out... the problem started with 10.10.3

Comment: I have a similar issue on a swift application when using a JS bridge. Opening a bug report with Apple resulted in `Duplicate of 13811738 (Open)`
EDIT: the issue seam to happen randomly

Comment: i use a JS bridge too!

Comment: is there any info to the bug 13811738 ?

Comment: Instead of enabling NSZombie directly, how about using the Zombies instrument in Instruments? Also, you should send -stopLoading: to the web view itself. It may be that the web view is still dealing with resources and sending the stop to the web view itself (instead of its main frame) might make it happy. Doubtful, but a suggestion.

Comment: the webview in OSX doesn't have stopLoading, but iam using [[self.webView mainFrame] stopLoading];

Comment: See the marked answer, all solved for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed you're using your own policy delegate:

```
[self.webView setPolicyDelegate:nil];
```

There's a known bug related to policy delegates in WebKit (only very recently fixed):

https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=144975

The short version is that you're probably hitting this assertion (which crashes the process with an intentional segfault):

https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/blob/24b1ae89efc10a4e6a6057b429c8e1d8d138a32f/Source/WebCore/loader/DocumentLoader.cpp#L935

because your policy handler (i.e. `decidePolicyForMIMEType:request:frame:decisionListener:`) is failing to make a policy decision (i.e not `use`, `ignore`, or `download`). The decision hangs around unmade, and when the loader eventually detaches it asserts that there are no pending policy decisions, which fails since the view is still waiting for a decision.

Answer (score 1):

The fix i made, is not to release the webview, but hold a static reference into it (this is far from solving it and i contacted Apple regarding this issue)

```
#warning HOTFIX
{
    //this is because of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29746074/osx-10-10-3-crashes-webview-on-dealloc
    static NSMutableArray * LIVE_FOR_EVER_WEBVIEW;

    if (LIVE_FOR_EVER_WEBVIEW == nil) {
        LIVE_FOR_EVER_WEBVIEW = [NSMutableArray new];
    }
    if (self.webView) {
        [LIVE_FOR_EVER_WEBVIEW addObject:self.webView];
    }
}
```